# C# Checking textbox text is the same as values from database stored in the list

Tags: c#, mysql, list, contains

I know why I am getting this error, but I do not know a way around it.

1. I am trying to check if the answers the user types into the textbox is correct.
2. I will do this by checking the answer against the answer in the database.
3. I have stored the contents from the database into a list so I can compare the users answer against the correct answer.

   ```
     {
       string mydbConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;Initial Catalog=project;username=xxx;password=xxx;";
       MySqlConnection connDB = new MySqlConnection(mydbConnection);
       MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("SELECT questions.answer FROM questions;", connDB);
       MySqlDataReader DBReader;
       connDB.Open();
       DBReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
       while (DBReader.Read())
       {
           List<string> answers = new List<string>();
           for (int i = 0; i < DBReader.FieldCount; i++)
               answers.Add(DBReader.GetValue(i).ToString());

           for (int i = 0; i < answers.Count; i++)
           {
               if (answers[i].Contains(textBoxQ1, textBoxQ2, textBoxQ3, textBoxQ4, textBoxQ5, textBoxQ6, textBoxQ7, textBoxQ8, textBoxQ9, textBoxQ10))
               {
                   label1.Text = "Well done, Correct Answer";
               }
               else
               {
                   label1.Text = "unlucky, wrong answer";
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   I am getting the error:

> No overload for method 'Contains' takes 10 arguments

I know why I am getting the error. I think it is because the method 'contains' can only take 1 parameter. However I do not know how a way around this. My question is HOW can I amend by code to achieve this objective?

EDIT:

Comment: Your first task is to change the password because now everyone knows what it is.

Comment: The code is very  far from being correct. Think about this: Every input represents a certain question. You need to check whether the answer given by the user is the correct answer for the specific question. How do you know which question is shown for textBoxQ1, which is shown for textBoxQ2, and so on?

Comment: I have a another function which calls the questions from the database populates the datagridview which the user can view. If I can crack the answering function, I can crack this project. And yes I still need to adjust it. I am stuck on how to check the answer given by the user is the correct answer for the specific questions. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, show us how you populate the questions. This is essential to know how to check the answers.

Comment: I don't see how they are linked. But there u go, I edited the question with the questions code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you retrieve the questions from the database, for each question you retrieve the question text and the questionID.

Later on, use the questionID to get the correct answer for that individual question. For example when you have question with questionid 42, you can get the correct answer for that question via

```
select answer from questions where questionID = 42;
```

Now perform the following in your application:

For each answer entered by the user, retrieve the questionID from the grid. Then retrieve the correct answer for that question from the database via the statement shown above. Then compare that answer with the answer entered by user in the corresponding TextBox.

---

Another alternative is that you already get the correct answers from the database when populating the questions and store the answer in a hidden column in the DataGridView. Then you do not even have to go to the database again to check the answers, but can just compare the answer given by the user to the answer already stored in the DataGridView.

Some sample code for this second approach, not using a database, but initializing the datagrid manually.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Fill data grid
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    dataTable.Columns.Add("QuestionID");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Question");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Answer");

    dataTable.Rows.Add(1, "5 + 4", "9");
    dataTable.Rows.Add(2, "Capital of Germany", "Berlin");
    dataTable.Rows.Add(23, "Angela ...", "Merkel");
    dataTable.Rows.Add(42, "Capital of France", "Paris");

    dataGridViewQuiz.DataSource = dataTable;

    // Hide id and answer
    dataGridViewQuiz.Columns["QuestionID"].Visible = false;
    dataGridViewQuiz.Columns["Answer"].Visible = false;
}

// function to check an individual answer from a given TextBox
// against a given row in the datagrid.
private bool CheckAnswer(DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow, TextBox textBox)
{
    string correctAnswer = dataGridViewRow.Cells["Answer"].Value.ToString();
    string givenAnswer = textBox.Text;

    bool isCorrect = string.Equals(correctAnswer, givenAnswer, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);

    return isCorrect;
}

private void buttonCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool firstAnswerCorrect = CheckAnswer(dataGridViewQuiz.Rows[0], textBoxQ1);
    bool secondAnswerCorrect = CheckAnswer(dataGridViewQuiz.Rows[1], textBoxQ2);
    bool thirdAnswerCorrect = CheckAnswer(dataGridViewQuiz.Rows[2], textBoxQ3);
    bool fourthAnswerCorrect = CheckAnswer(dataGridViewQuiz.Rows[3], textBoxQ4);
}
```

Comment: No source code answer since this is obviously a homework project, but trying to explain the steps to take. If something is unclear, please ask and I can give a more detailed answer.

Comment: That sounds great!  i will give it a go and if i need further assistance i will get back to you. Thanks. also this is not a homework project but no worries i love a challenge.

Comment: I understand the gist of your code. However referring to your 'checkAnswer' function does it return a true/false if it is the same as the answer in the datagrid?

Comment: Yes, it returns true or false depending on whether the answer in the textbox is the same as the one stored in the datagridview row.

Answer (score -1):

If u want to check if multiple conditions are being meet you could use a and.